# Same log4j2 xml but with different output

Tags: java, log4j

During my last semester I've worked on a project and now I'll rewrite it from scratch to improve on my mistakes and improve the model.

Currently I'm struggeling as I'm not getting the output I'm used to when something should be logged. I wan't it to be output to the console and written to the .log file.

Log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorinterval="60" status="DEBUG" strict="true">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">logs/gastro.log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="Console" name="Console">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%d %p [%t] %m%n" />
        </Appender>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${filename}"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" lefel="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The output to the console:

```
Replaced in edit
```

My test class where I just log a tesmessage:

```
public class PersonDAOTest {

    PersonDAO personDAO = new PersonDAOImpl();

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersonDAOTest.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Util.deleteAllPerson();
    }

    public void init() throws Exception {
        Util.createPersonList();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testSave() throws Exception {
        init();
        assertTrue(personDAO.findAll().size() == Util.INIT_SIZE_PERSON);
    }

    @Test
    public final void findByUsername() throws Exception {
        init();
        assertTrue(personDAO.findByUsername("mmarco").getSurname().equals("Meier"));
        logger.info("Hello");
    }

    @Test
    public final void findBySurnameAndForename() throws Exception {
        init();
        assertTrue(personDAO.findBySurnameAndForename("Meier", "Marco").size() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public final void findBySurname() throws Exception {
        init();
        assertTrue(personDAO.findBySurname("Meier").size() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public final void findByForename() throws Exception {
        init();
        assertTrue(personDAO.findByForename("Marco").size() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public final void updatePerson() throws Exception {
        init();
        Person person = personDAO.findAllPerson().get(0);
        Person personToCompareTo = personDAO.findAllPerson().get(0);
        person.setForename("TestName");
        personDAO.update(person);
        assertTrue(personDAO.findByForename("TestName").size() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public final void deletePerson() throws Exception {
        init();
        int listSizeBeforeDelete = personDAO.findAllPerson().size();
        personDAO.delete(personDAO.findAllPerson().get(0));
        assertTrue(listSizeBeforeDelete != personDAO.findAllPerson().size());
    }
}
```

I would like that the console output would be the same is what is written to the file:

```
18.06.2018 15:19:51:786- PersonDAOTest: Hello
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

configuration status = trace:

```
2018-06-18 16:05:28,496 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2018-06-18 16:05:28,504 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2018-06-18 16:05:28,813 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_171, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2018-06-18 16:05:28,814 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 107 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,814 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,821 main DEBUG 1 starting Log4j2 ConfigurationScheduler threads
2018-06-18 16:05:28,824 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,835 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,836 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,845 main DEBUG createProperty(name="filename", value="logs/gastro.log")
2018-06-18 16:05:28,845 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,849 main DEBUG configureSubstitutor(={filename=logs/gastro.log}, Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
2018-06-18 16:05:28,850 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,851 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,857 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %p [%t] %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2018-06-18 16:05:28,857 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,872 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,880 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="null", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %p [%t] %m%n), name="Console", Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,880 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-06-18 16:05:28,881 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2018-06-18 16:05:28,881 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,882 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2018-06-18 16:05:28,882 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,884 main DEBUG createPolicy(size="1000 KB")
2018-06-18 16:05:28,885 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,886 main DEBUG createPolicy(={SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1024000)})
2018-06-18 16:05:28,887 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,888 main DEBUG createStrategy(max="4", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={}, stopCustomActionsOnError="true", Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
2018-06-18 16:05:28,889 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,892 main DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="logs/gastro.log", filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1024000)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=4)), advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml), bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n), name="RollingFile", Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,895 main TRACE New file 'logs/gastro.log' created = false
2018-06-18 16:05:28,895 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager logs/gastro.log
2018-06-18 16:05:28,896 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2018-06-18 16:05:28,897 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,898 main DEBUG createAppenders(={Console, RollingFile})
2018-06-18 16:05:28,898 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,898 main ERROR appender-ref contains an invalid element or attribute "lefel"
2018-06-18 16:05:28,898 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,899 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,899 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="RollingFile", level="DEBUG", Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,899 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,900 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="root", includeLocation="null", ={Console, RollingFile}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,903 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,904 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="RollingFile", level="null", Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,904 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,905 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={RollingFile}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2018-06-18 16:05:28,905 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2018-06-18 16:05:28,906 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root, root})
2018-06-18 16:05:28,906 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml] initialized
2018-06-18 16:05:28,906 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2018-06-18 16:05:28,908 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,908 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@2ac1fdc4...
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2018-06-18 16:05:28,909 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2018-06-18 16:05:28,910 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,910 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,910 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@2ac1fdc4 OK
2018-06-18 16:05:28,961 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@7dc0f706
2018-06-18 16:05:28,962 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306
2018-06-18 16:05:28,963 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,963 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,963 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,964 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,964 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=*'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,964 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,964 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,965 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2018-06-18 16:05:28,966 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
2018-06-18 16:05:28,969 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
2018-06-18 16:05:28,971 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
2018-06-18 16:05:28,972 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
2018-06-18 16:05:28,974 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=Console
2018-06-18 16:05:28,974 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile
2018-06-18 16:05:28,976 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,976 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,976 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306) with optional ClassLoader: null
2018-06-18 16:05:28,977 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2018-06-18 16:05:28,978 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306] started OK.
[EL Info]: 2018-06-18 16:05:29.69--ServerSession(576894497)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5
[EL Info]: connection: 2018-06-18 16:05:29.891--ServerSession(576894497)--/file:/C:/Users/My Name/Documents/Dev/GastronomySoftware/gastronomysoftware-persister/target/classes/_JpaDemosPU login successful
2018-06-18 16:05:30,075 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,075 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306]...
2018-06-18 16:05:30,075 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,076 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,076 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,076 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering 2 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=Console]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml]...
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration notified 2 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,077 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping 1 LoggerConfigs.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,078 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,078 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,078 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,078 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager logs/gastro.log
2018-06-18 16:05:30,079 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down RollingFileManager logs/gastro.log, all resources released: true
2018-06-18 16:05:30,080 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2018-06-18 16:05:30,080 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false, all resources released: true
2018-06-18 16:05:30,080 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration stopped 2 remaining Appenders.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,080 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE XmlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 2 LoggerConfigs.
2018-06-18 16:05:30,080 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Log4j2 ConfigurationScheduler shutting down threads in java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@41bf32e3[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
2018-06-18 16:05:30,081 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Dev\GastronomySoftware\gastronomysoftware-persister\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK
2018-06-18 16:05:30,081 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4009e306]...
```

Comment: look at the pattern in the console and file appenders. If you want the output to be the same between the appenders, use the same pattern.

Comment: I'm using the exact same .xml in a different project and it works perfectly there.

Comment: then it's not this xml file setting up log4j... add `-Dlog4j.debug` to your command line and the console should show details of which file, what appenders and what patterns are being used. Your console pattern has following `[%t]` which means that thread name in the output would be in the square brackets, but clearly isn't.

Comment: Hope I understood you correctly, I've added   -Dlog4j.debug  under enviroment variables in intelliJ and run the test again. There wasn't any log4j2 information suggesting anything, I have then set the configuration status to trace which should do the same thing and edited my original post.

Comment: You have to add it as a VM Option in your Run Configuration

Comment: `-Dlog4j.debug` is from 2.9, before 2.9 you need: `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#troubleshooting